# Insertion prevent trigger with logical error condition

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I'm trying to prevent update `Card1 and Card2` to user on table `refer` who has less money than required on table **total_balance.**`total_money`

Is it possible to complate such logic with trigger?

```
    DELIMITER $$
        CREATE trigger LessMoneyThanRequirePrevent
        Before update ON refer
        FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
           IF (total_balance.total_money<10 WHERE total_balance.username= NEW.refer.username)
              THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Not enough money in your account! Insertion canceled';
              END IF;
         END
        $$
        DELIMITER;
```

**I think problem on WHERE condition??**

Table: **refer**

```
 ID        username        Card1        Card2  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   1   |  John       |  Value      |    Value  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  Alex       |  Null       |    Null   |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Table: **total_balance**

```
 ID        username     total_money        
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   1   |  John       |     10.0    |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   2   |  Alex       |     7.0     |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

***For example:*** User John has enough money on `total_balance` and **allowed to update** `Card1 and Card2` but Alex not enough **not allowed**

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the IF condition. The following is the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE trigger LessMoneyThanRequirePrevent
Before update ON refer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM total_balance b WHERE b.total_money<10 AND b.username= NEW.username)
   THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Not enough money in your account! Insertion canceled';
   END IF;
END
$$
```

Comment: I should not Select exactly one user! It should prevent to all who has less than required money!

Comment: The trigger is on refer table and is for whoever updating the record, not for particular user.

Comment: complete trigger is included

Comment: FWIW, seems to me like we would want the condition to be checked the other way around. if there exists a matching row with balance >= 10, then we allow the update to proceed, otherwise we raise an error. Consider what should happen for example if there isn't any matching "Alex" row in the `total_balance` table. Do we want to allow an update to `refer` table? It depends on the specification, which I don't really have an understanding of, but comparing to cases where I might have used a trigger to enforce something like this, I would tend to affirm "yes, this user has enough total_money"